# Native.withOrientation is not a function

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm working on building a react app for the first time, but I'm getting back an error whenever I run the code on android emulator. 
[image]

Here is my App.js file:

```
import React from "react";
import { Dimensions } from "react-native";
import {
  createStackNavigator,
  createSwitchNavigator,
  createAppContainer,
  createDrawerNavigator,
  createMaterialTopTabNavigator
} from "react-navigation";
import Icon from "@expo/vector-icons/Ionicons";
import Login from "./src/views/Login";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <AppContainer />;
  }
}
```

And my app.json is:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "eCommerce",
    "slug": "eCommerce",
    "privacy": "public",
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android"
    ],
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    }
  }
}
```

This is my package.json file:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
   "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.8",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.1.5",
    "expo": "^35.0.0",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-35.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.3.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.2.0",
    "react-native-responsive-screen": "^1.4.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.3.6",
    "react-native-screens": "^1.0.0-alpha.23",
    "react-native-star-rating": "^1.1.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^7.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Note: I removed part of the App.js code because they are too long, but that's the general structure.

Can anyone help with what might be the cause of this issue?
Thanks

Comment: please also share package.json. it is not about in your code

Comment: Thanks @Çağrı, I've done that

Comment: https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/3216

Comment: I've tried using the procedures started in that link, but still can't get it work for me